# How to convert a text file into a list?

Tags: python

I have a simple text file that has 10 names in it. I want to open it with Python and count how many names are there and how many times each name appears in the text file.

My problem is that I don't manage to make the program understand that there are 10 names on the text file. The program counts the whole list just as one name. How to fix this?

This is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
count = 0
f = open("names.txt", "r")
with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
   newlist = f.read().splitlines()
   count = count + 1
   names = Counter(line[14:] for line in newlist)
print("There are this many names on the list:",count)
print(names) #Here I would like the names to appear as well as count how many times a particular name appears on the list #
```

Comment: You only increment count once...

Comment: what does `14` mean?

Comment: There is no need to use `Counter` for this fundamental task.

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the text file?

Comment: You should not have `f = open('names.txt','r')` in your code at all. This is accomplished, and accomplished better, in the next line `with open(...) as f:`. That `with` block opens the file and makes sure to close it at the end of the block. You can completely remove the `f = open(...)`

Comment: After the `with ... as f:` do `names = {line[14:] for line in f}` and then `count = len(names)`.

Answer (score 0):

To count how many names there are in the list, split it by it‘s lines and then get the length of the list.

```
f = open("names.txt", "r")
with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
   newlist = f.read().splitlines()
   count = len(newlist)
print("There are this many names on the list:",count)
```

Your mistake was that you only incremented count once, in this example, count is being set to the length of the list split by newlines.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out how many unique names you have in the list you just need to check the length of the `names` counter object. Here is an example:

```
with open("names.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("              Peter\n")
    f.write("              John\n")
    f.write("              James\n")
    f.write("              Bart\n")

from collections import Counter
count = 0

with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
    newlist = f.read().splitlines()
    names = Counter(line[14:] for line in newlist)
print("There are this many names on the list:",count)

print(len(names))
```

This prints `4`, which is the length of unique names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. It assumes that there is a single name per line in the file.

```py
from collections import Counter

with open('names.txt', 'r') as file:
    names = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

counter = Counter(names)
print(f'Total number of names: {len(names)}')
print(f'Total number of unique names: {len(counter)}')
for name, count in counter.items():
    print(f'{name}: {count}')
```

You can also do it without creating a list by using generator expression and instead of calling readlines() method you can just iterate on the file object.

```py
with open('names.txt', 'r') as file:
    counter = Counter(line.strip() for line in file)

print(f'Total number of names: {sum(counter.values())}')
print(f'Total number of unique names: {len(counter)}')
for name, count in counter.items():
    print(f'{name}: {count}')
```

Comment: Amazing!! Now it looks just like it should. Thanks! Will make notes about this solution :)